# Join two collections and return only matching documents instead of all documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to Join two collections and return specific documents from mongoDB using mongoose JS library and be able to return this data back to user using get request, I tried so far:

user_language.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userLanguageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  is_native: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    max: 1,
  },
  user: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
  languages: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Language',
  }],
}, {timestamps: true});

const UserLanguage = mongoose.model("UserLanguage", UserLanguageSchema);

module.exports = UserLanguage;
```

timetable.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TimeTableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  timetable_date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  user: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }],
  call_requests: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'CallRequest',
  }],
}, {timestamps: true});

const TimeTable = mongoose.model("TimeTable", TimeTableSchema);

module.exports = TimeTable;
```

routes.js:

```
app.get("/find_user?param1&param2", auth, async (request, response) => {
  const userLanguage = await userLanguageModel.aggregate({ 
    $lookup:{
      from: "timetable",
      localField: "user._id",
      foreignField: "user._id",
      as: "userLanguageAndTimeTable"
    }
   });
```

I know above get request is not complete (that's what I need help with), eventually I want something like this:

```
select user.username, user.language, timetable.timetable_date from user inner join timetable on user.username = timetable.username
and user.language = ? and time_table.time_table_date = ?;
```

Be able to get user language and user timetable from two separate collections based on user input

Sample input data from timetable collection:

```
{
    "_id": "623ddd123d2ae23a7ae1a4ee",
    "timetable_date": "2022-03-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "user": [
        "621284a95f2df9167e48b6c9"
    ],
    "createdAt": "2022-03-25T15:17:38.307Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-25T19:49:36.318Z",
    "__v": 5,
    "call_requests": []
}
```

Sample input data from user_language collection:

```
{
    "_id": "62403255a4e974c66beceeb1",
    "is_native": 1,
    "user": [
        "621284a95f2df9167e48b6c9"
    ],
    "languages": [
        {
            "_id": "621333613725998148be357b",
            "language": "Persian",
            "code": "code-3",
            "__v": 10,
            "call_requests": [
                "623e0ec924b1dd4470dcfbf7",
                "623e221530d164d8e6d3c153"
            ],
            "user_languages": []
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2022-03-27T09:45:57.650Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-27T09:45:57.650Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
   "_id": "62403255a4e974cd3444ece153",
   "user_language": {
       "_id": "62403255a4e974c66beceeb1",
       "user: [
          "621284a95f2df9167e48b6c9" 
        ],
       "languages": [
           {
            "_id": "621333613725998148be357b",
            "language": "Persian",
            "code": "code-3",
            "__v": 10,
            "call_requests": [
                "623e0ec924b1dd4470dcfbf7",
                "623e221530d164d8e6d3c153"
            ],
            "user_languages": []
           }
        ]
     },
     "timetable": {
       "_id": "623ddd123d2ae23a7ae1a4ee",
       "timetable_date": "2022-03-25T00:00:00.000Z",
       "user": [
        "621284a95f2df9167e48b6c9"
       ],
       "createdAt": "2022-03-25T15:17:38.307Z",
       "updatedAt": "2022-03-25T19:49:36.318Z",
       "__v": 5,
       "call_requests": []
     } 
}
```

Comment: can you provide some sample input data and your expected output?

Comment: What is param1 and param2?

Comment: @1sina1 Added input and output data.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor is param1 = userLanguage.language and param2 = timetable.timetable_date